# How will I know the signal strength of my smartphone's 3g?

Tags: 3g, network-signal

How will I determine the signal strength of my smartphone's 3G whether strong or weak?

[image]

Comment: check  right angled triangle symbols, to the left of H with arrows. if they are completely white colored , signal is strong, else it degrades to lower.

Comment: Try [Signal level notification](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=info.narazaki.android.signalnotification&hl=en) app.

Comment: The title seems on-topic but the body appears to be off-topic. It is Android independent because signal strength is not Android specific thing.

Answer (score 0):

To see the **signal strength**:

- Go to Settings → About phone → Status.
- For dual sim phones: go to Settings → About phone → Status → SIM status.